# Angular-Seed npm start bower component errors

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, bower, angular-seed

When I start a project with angular-seed from https://github.com/areai51/angular-seed/ I do

```
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/areai51/angular-seed/ myproject
npm install
npm start
```

This launches the web server fine. However, when navigating to localhost:8000/app/index.html, all of the bower components fail to load. It is caused by them being installed into myproject/bower_components instead of myproject/app/bower_components. How do I fix this so that my bower components are loaded correctly?

EDIT: After erasing the directory and reinstalling, bower_components seemed to be placed in the correct location. Solved for now.

Comment: The bower_components is in the correct directory, what do you say that it is not correct directory?

Comment: When you run npm install, after install the script run automatically bower install (take a look a package json). When bower install run, there throw  any error?

Comment: bower install throws no errors. I say it is in the incorrect directory because the following style errors are produced (many of them) GET http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I made the same steps, and it work fine. Did you modified the package json? Verify that you run these command in the root of the project! @AMB9927